# Solving Coupled System of Differential Equations With MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I need help writing this code in Matlab, [image: my code is here]

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x-2y+1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 3y-3x$$

Using MATLAB, construct a phase portrait using the quiver command. Then, approximate the solutions for the initial conditions Y(0) = (-1,3), Y(0) = (-1,-2), and Y(0) = (1,1). Your solutions should be plotted from t = 0 to t = 10 on the same axes as your phase portrait. The graph should include a legend so that the solutions are clearly visible. Make comments about both the phase portrait and your solutions.

Also, if there is any version of pplane8 that works with MATLAB 2017B that would also be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm fairly sure matlab has its own SE, and good documentation. Also the question indicates you are struggling with knowing/using a function in MATLAB, what functions have you tried already?

Comment: Time initial is set to -1, instead of 0, are you sure about this? For loop on line 23, I think that wont run and should be changed to ti:tf:ts or some other combination

Comment: The code executes as it is right now, but does not give a graph that is correct, and does not give a phase portrait at all. ti:tf:ts did not execute. This code was used as an euler's method in a previous problem and was correct.

Comment: Consider adding print statements, it may help you understand what matlab is doing (and yes, I misread the code originally, I have a better idea of what you want to do now, although I still think ti should be 0